# How to load Collection data types using spark-cassandra connector in batch mode

Tags: apache-spark, collections, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to load a spark dataframe which has two attributes with collection datatypes into a Cassandra table.

In the incoming feed file, these attributes are text/String.  I used the below code to convert the String type to List and Map types respectively:

```
    spark.udf.register("getLst", (input: String) => input.split(",").toList)

    spark.udf.register("getMap", (input:String) => parse(input).values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]])

    val ofr_data_final=spark.sql("""select  
            ...
            getLst(acct_nb_ls) as acct_nb_ls, 
            getMap(brw_eci_and_sts_mp) as brw_eci_and_sts_mp, 
            .....""")
```

The print schema of the spark dataframe shows those two attributes as shown below:

```
    |-- acct_nb_ls: array (nullable = true)
    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
    |-- brw_eci_and_sts_mp: map (nullable = true)
    |    |-- key: string
    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

In Cassandra, those two attributes are defined as shown below:

```
    acct_nb_ls FROZEN<LIST<text>>,
    brw_eci_and_sts_mp FROZEN<MAP<text, text>>,
```

Here is my load statement:

```
    ofr_data_final.rdd.saveToCassandra(Config.keySpace,offerTable, writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.perRow("ttl")))
```

However the load fails with the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 140 in stage 24.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 140.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 1741, bdtcstr70n12.svr.us.jpmchase.net, executor 9): java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to mars_offerdetails.offer_detail_2.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1517)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1732)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1687)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1676)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.jpmc.mars.LoadOfferData$.delayedEndpoint$com$jpmc$mars$LoadOfferData$1(LoadOfferData.scala:246)
    at com.jpmc.mars.LoadOfferData$delayedInit$body.apply(LoadOfferData.scala:22)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
    at com.jpmc.mars.LoadOfferData$.main(LoadOfferData.scala:22)
    at com.jpmc.mars.LoadOfferData.main(LoadOfferData.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to write statements to mars_offerdetails.offer_detail_2.
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:167)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter.write(TableWriter.scala:135)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveToCassandra$1.apply(RDDFunctions.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I suspect the issue might be because the attribute acct_nb_lst is inferred as 'array' and not as 'list'  but I am not sure how to make spark infer it as 'list' instead of 'array'.  In my UDF, I had defined mentioned

```
    input.split(",").toList
```

but still it's getting inferred as array.

Comment: We are able to load the file if use ofr_data_final.write.cassandraFormat instead of ofr_data_final.rdd.saveToCassandra(Config.keySpace,offerTable, writeConf = WriteConf(ttl = TTLOption.perRow("ttl"))).  But, in df.write, we are not able to specify ttl option at record level.

Comment: Spark Cassandra connector doesn't support it for DataFrames (yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading collection data types using spark-cassandra connector in batch mode worked as expected with ttl option on record level using rdd.saveToCassandra.  The issue was with the data.  The data was old and had past expired dates which generated negative ttl values and hence the load failed.

Spark error message should be enhanced to imply that.